# Установка pip на python3.7 в Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ctypes

После установки python3.7 не вызывается pip

```
python3.7 -m pip3
/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip3

python3.7 -m pip
/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip
```

Я скачиваю pip

```
sudo wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

Пытаюсь установить

```
python3.7 get-pip.py
```

Получаю ошибку

```
python3.7 get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20890, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/download.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp_tcj3qgb/pip.zip/pip/_internal/utils/glibc.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Comment: Пип вызывается просто ``pip``/``pip3``. Никаких ``python -m`` перед этим не надо.

Comment: Тогда при pip3 пакет устанавливается в python  3.6.6, а не в python 3.7

Comment: Пип устанавливает вместе с питоном, его вообще не надо дополнительно устанавливать. Если у вас запускается из 3.6 то нужно или удалить питон 3.6 или подправить переменные окружения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблему помогло решить:

```
sudo ln -sf python3.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Теперь просто вызываю `pip3`

Answer (score 1):

У меня на убунту сервер Ubuntu 19.10 что на сайте расберри дают получилось так:

```
apt install python3-pip
pip3 install fpdf
```